# diff of two files from two different directories

Tags: perl, diff

I have two or more directories which contains an ample of files.

I want to take a diff between the two files(which will be of same name for sure) but exists in different directories.Please help on how can in do this in perl scripting.Thanks.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Perl to accomplish it.

Try:

```
diff -r -N folder1/ folder2/
```

Comment: This does not work well because there are new files in folder 1 whcih are not in folder 2.So the diff generated is in chunk....The filename should be the input.Only then this will resolve

Comment: What do you want to do with files not present in folder2? Ignore them?

Comment: Yes.The files not present must be ignored